# Is a bunch of if/else statements in python considered an AI?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

So I'm making a TicTacToe "AI" and the code itself doesn't have any deep learning implications such as Tensor flow in min-max algorithms. The code simply consists of a jumble of if/else statements. My question is: can my code be considered an Artificial Intelligence because I'm literally training the code to play tic tac toe in a certain way when a player selects an area of play?

Comment: AI potentially would be able to add new additions to its learning capability. Does your code add some more if/else apart from the one you coded? If no, then this is not AI :)

Comment: @JimTodd what you're describing is Machine Learning. AI has a lower bar.

Comment: I believe ML is a subset of AI. So, AI would include ML techniques. However, I am not an expert in this area. So would not prove my point.

Comment: @JimTodd I'm not an expert either, and colloquially I think if you used the term "artificial intelligence" it's clear that you mean something with ML, but also in gaming "I played against the AI" is clear to mean a thing that almost certainly does NOT use ML. Natural language is weird.

Comment: There is [a book](https://i.redd.it/57gmyswprqm01.jpg) about it :o). More seriously, this should be closed as primarily opinion based. But if you want my opinion there isn't a clear line between what is a calculator and what is a brain.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with actual programming. It is about a program but not programmING.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is not the question you were looking for Dave.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This IEEE publication](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=551) has the following to say on the subject:

> The term artificial intelligence denotes behavior of a
>   machine which, if a human behaves in the same way, is
>   considered intelligent.
>
> It is difficult to extend this definition, because the definition
>   of what factors describe human intelligence is not clear.

Tic-Tac-Toe is a very simple game, so it is very easy to make a simple application behave exactly the same as an intelligent human would. So, if this is the definition of artificial intelligence to which you subscribe, then yes, you would be justified in calling your "jumble of if/else statements" an AI.

However, if you tell someone you wrote a Tic-Tac-Toe AI, they will immediately know that it is either (a) too complicated for what you're applying it to, or (b) not really very intelligent at all, but functional for its task.

The problem arises when people use "artificial intelligence" as a buzzword (buzzphrase?) that obscures how the AI is making decisions, which could potentially be because it's an ML black-box and they can't tell you exactly how it works either, or because they want to sell a product that sounds fancy but is actually just a jumble of if/else statements (or simply would not benefit from explaining it in detail in place of just saying "it's AI").

In this case I feel like it is a safe, if somewhat useless, application of the term.

Comment: "The term artificial intelligence denotes behavior of a machine which, if a human behaves in the same way, is considered intelligent.".  If we say a person that can calculate a production of 2 numbers, with any of them with 10 digits, in less than 1 second, we will considered they as an intelligent person. Does it means that python script that calculate it is AI?

Comment: AI has also been defined as "[machines that do something](https://youtu.be/W1S-HSakPTM?t=25m12s)." By that notion, the term AI is extremely broad. It could also be argued that AI does not have to be intelligent in order to be considered AI. A non-player character in a computer game for example, is often referred to as "the AI," and still it can (although it shouldn't in order to create an fun and immersive gaming experience) behave in ways that the player would consider rather stupid.

Answer (score 3):

This is really a question about word definition more than programming, but per [artificial-intelligence](/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence):

> This tag may also refer to the part of a computer game application that controls the behavior of the virtual characters with which the player may interact during the game.

So I guess in the context on Stack Overflow: yes, a tic-tac-toe decision tree is an AI.

Answer (score 2):

> In artificial intelligence, an intelligent agent (IA) is an autonomous
>   entity which observes through sensors and acts upon an environment
>   using actuators (i.e., it is an agent) and directs its activity
>   towards achieving goals.

Some agents are simple, and some agents are complex. A simple if/else statement is a very simple intelligent agent.

AI is not new. John McCarthy coined the term in 1955 and organized the first Artificial Intelligence conference in 1956. 
In the last few decades, we have cracked building scalable intelligent agents that solve hard problems very fast; thanks to the technological improvement, faster & cheaper hardware & years of research by great people.

So a simple if/else is an intelligent agent considered as AI by the pioneers of AI whose tremendous work & years of research been open sourced resulted in building complex intelligent agents faster and simpler.

The definition of an intelligent agent coined by Stuart Russell and Peter Norvig in the book Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach. In the introduction of the book, the authors cited this example of simple if/else and confirmed that it's a simple, intelligent agent.

**The credibility of the Book:**

- The leading textbook in Artificial Intelligence.
- Used in over 1400 universities in over 125 countries.
- The 22nd most cited computer science publication on Citeseer (and 4th most cited publication of this century).

**The credibility of the Authors:**

1. Stuart Russell, Ph.D., Computer Science, Stanford University
2. Peter Norvig, Director of Research at Google

**My references:**

- Inteligent Agent [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_agent)
- John McCarthy [link](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/58/who-first-coined-the-term-artificial-intelligence)
- The credibility of the Book [aima.cs.berkeley.edu](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/)
- Norvig Resume [link](http://www.norvig.com/resume.html)
- Russell Resume [link](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~russell/resume.html)